# React: routed Component should stay until animation is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-router

I want my "About" Component to stay until the animation of the new Component is done!

Thats my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import Projects from './components/Projects';
import About from './components/About';
import PageShell from './components/PageShell';
import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <div className="App-main">
          <Route path="/projects" exact component={PageShell(Projects)}/>
          <Route path="/" exact component={PageShell(About)}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

PageShell.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

const PageShell = Page => {
 return props =>
 <div className="page">
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName={props.match.path === '/projects' ? 'slideIn' : 'slideOut'}
    transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
    transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={2000}
    transitionAppear={true}
    >
     <Page {...props} />
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
 </div>;
};

export default PageShell;
```

When i click on a div in the About-Page, it disappear instantly and the animation for the Project-Page starts. But i want the About-Compinent to stay until Projects slided in. Projects should be above About.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using react-router-transitions library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-transition

Comment: no, i have not. I will try it :)

Comment: yap, solved my problem. THANKS!